# How to create a new div with unique Id using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Apologies if this has already been asked. There are similar questions but none seemed to explain the best way of doing this.

Say i have the following code:

```
<div id ="test"> hello </div>
```

And i want to insert a new div box with id "test 2" within this div. What would be the easiest method using Jquery?

Comment: You could use `.append()` to add html code after the end of the html code in the container (which is the aim of this method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append another div dynamically to existing div by following way

```
$( "#test" ).append( '<div id="test2">Test</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Script**

```
var contentString = "<div id='test2'></div>"
$("#test").append(contentString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way I think

```
var Div_2 = $("<div></div>").attr("id","test 2");
Div_2.appendTo($("#test"))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyecsuwf/)

```
var div2 = $("<div id='test2'>")
$("#test").append(div2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test2").appendTo("#test");
```

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
        var divCount = 0;
        $( "#create" ).click(function() {
          $( "#contents" ).append( '<div id="div' + divCount + '">div id=div' + divCount + '</div>');  
          divCount++;
        });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contents"></div>
    <a href="#" id="create">Add new div</a>
</body>
</html>
```